# Looking for a plain-looking XeLaTeX thesis template, for transfer from ClassicThesis template

Tags: xetex, templates, classicthesis, thesis

I learnt LaTeX for my M.A. dissertation, using the `ClassicThesis` template. It is beautiful and works fine. But my University (in Vietnam) has requirements on format that are not compatible with `ClassicThesis`. So I am looking for a template that

1. complies with the University's requirements

   - A4 single-sided
   - section numbering: 1, 1.1, 1.1.1
   - page numbering at bottom
   - TimesNewRoman, 13-point, 1.5 line spacing
2. is close enough to `ClassicThesis` to facilitate the transfer of contents from one template to another.

It's paradoxical to try to do plain (...erm... ugly!) things in XeLaTeX, because the whole idea of LaTeX is to create beautiful books. But that's where I am now: there's no escaping University regulations!
This template: https://github.com/zachscrivena/another-latex-thesis-template would be just fine, but it's not  XeLaTeX and the packages that I use for language encoding (`babel`, `fontenc`) require XeLaTeX. (I use various languages and special symbols.)

I am still a beginner, i.e. unable to change the templates, apart from simple changes such as choice of fonts (and even that is not easy for me).
Many thanks for indications

Comment: That is why one does better not use such convoluted and needlessly complicated boilerplate.  To learn more about how to use LaTeX properly, I recommend [Marc van Dongen's »LaTeX and friends«](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007%2F978-3-642-23816-1).

Comment: Can you perhaps show us your preamble (i.e. everything before `\begin{document}`). Maybe the necessary changes can be made along with keeping `classicthesis`.

Comment: Thanks Henri Menke for your good advice. Yes, I am aware that I am unfamiliar with important principles.

Comment: To Samcarter: Keeping classicthesis does not appear feasible to me because it is designed with great precision in detail (cf. Henri Menke's comment) and the University requirements are VERY different. In any case, here are (i) the passage for non-Roman, non-maths characters and (ii) the full contents of classicthesis-config.tex, the file that contains the Preamble for the classicthesis style.

Comment: (i) \usepackage{fontenc}
\newfontfamily{\thaifont}[Mapping=tex-text,Ligatures=Common,Scale=MatchUppercase]{Angsana New} %Thai
\newcommand{\thaiscript}[1]{{\thaifont #1}}
\newfontfamily\cn[Mapping=tex-text,Ligatures=Common,Scale=MatchUppercase]{MingLiU} %Chinese
\newcommand{\zh}[1]{{\cn #1}}
\newfontfamily\phon[Mapping=tex-text, Ligatures=Common, Scale=MatchLowercase, UprightFont={* Bold}]{Charis SIL} % IPA
\newcommand{\ipa}[1]{{\phon #1}}

Comment: (ii) https://www.dropbox.com/s/n7a3qrim9eg1ors/classicthesis-config.tex?dl=0

Comment: I think that the [`another-latex-thesis-template`](https://github.com/zachscrivena/another-latex-thesis-template) is adaptable to XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX. [I have done so.](https://github.com/wilx/another-latex-thesis-template) I claim no expertise or goodness of the result, only that it compiles and uses the style you have specified in OP. I have made some changes that were not necessary but I thought were beneficial. :)

Comment: Thanks again for answers. With some help from LaTeX users, I finally chose to use the memoir class

\documentclass[oldfontcommands,14pt,paper=a4,oneside]{memoir}

and to incorporate the commands I need one by one. It works now.

Comment: @Nguyễn: FYI, I've released a new XeLaTeX-based version of the thesis template [another-latex-thesis-template](https://github.com/zachscrivena/another-latex-thesis-template) which you were trying to use: [simple-thesis-dissertation](https://github.com/zachscrivena/simple-thesis-dissertation).

Comment: @Zach Scrivena: Thank you so much. I have finished my thesis so I would like to use your template for my PhD thesis or keep it as a good reference.